# show two analytic functions are not analytic continuations of each other

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, analytic-continuation, analytic-functions

Show that the series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ({1\over 1 - z^{n+1}} - {1\over 1-z^{n}})$

represents two analytic functions in the regions $|z| \lt 1$ and $|z| \gt 1$, and these functions are not analytic
continuations of each other.

Okay, so because the function is written as a series it is pretty obvious it is analytic. This is what I think I need to do:
Split the power series into two individual power series that can be represented as separate analytic continuations.

The problem I am having is that neither of the fractions in the series can be represented in a way that would let me work with a familiar power series-I've tried separating to get
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {1\over 1 - z^{n+1}}$ - $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {1\over 1-z^{n}}$ and then individually integrating each series which gives me log of something which is not useful and differentiating which just gives me something more complicated.
If I combine the two terms then seperate, I get
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ({z^{n+1}\over (1 - z^{n+1})(1-z^{n})} - {z^{n}\over (1-z^{n})(1-z^{n+1})})$ which is slightly similar to 
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {z^{n}}$ which I know can be analytically continued over $\frac{1}{1-z}$

I would appreciate any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: What does $\frac1{1-z^n}$ mean when $n=0\text{?}$  Or is the sum supposed to start at $n=1\text{?}$

Comment: @MitchellSpector that was a mistake on my part! I have edited to correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original sum is a telescoping series that can be written as

$lim_{n \to \infty}({1 \over1-z^{n+1}}-{1 \over1-z})$

This leads into two functions

a) $1- {1\over1-z}$ for $|z| < 1$

b) $- {1\over1-z}$ for $|z|>1$

If we expand these two in $\Bbb C-{\{1\}}$ then restricting one or the other in $D(0,1)$ or $\Bbb C-\hat D(0,1)$ then we can see that they are not the same.

Comment: Expanding the first function I have $${ 1 - \frac{1}{1-z}} = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z^{k+1}) = -z -z^{2} -z^{3}- ... $$

And the second

$${ - \frac{1}{1-z}} = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z^{k}) = -1 -z - z - ...$$

I am now uncertain of what it means to restrict the domains in this way.

Comment: By expanding, I mean expanding the domain. Both of these two are analytic in the whole plane besides $1$, so when in the first place we had functions inside the open unit disk and outside the closed disk respectively, now we have bigger functions. Restricting is just as trivial since neither functions are the same, so they can't be analytic continuations of each other.

Comment: Let me try and make it clearer. Let's say that $f_1, f_2$ are the (a) and (b) functions respectively. $f_1$ and $f_2$ are restrictions of $F_1, F_2$ (the same analytic functions defined in $\Bbb C -\{1\}$). Now, if $F_2$ is an analytic continuation of $f_1$ this means that they must be the same in the unit disk, which is obviously false if you try for example  $z=0$.